# sql syntax how to write it down in java

Tags: java, sql

i want to write this line in an sqlight db b:

```
CREATE TABLE "android_metadata" ("locale" TEXT DEFAULT 'en_US')
```

therefore in my java file who generate this data base i am doing :

```
stat.executeUpdate("create table "+"android_metadata"+"("+"locale"+ " TEXT DEAFULT"+");");
    PreparedStatement prep1 = conn.prepareStatement(
              "insert into "+"android_metadata"+" values (?);");
    prep1.setString(1, "en_US") ;
```

but the output is not similer how do i make the sqlight  locale be "locale" with "" in the declaration and the field locale would be just TEXT

as similer to this blog start : http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

thanX

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To escape the double quotes use a backslash:

```
stat.executeUpdate("create table \"android_metadata\" (\"locale\" TEXT DEFAULT 'en_US');");
```

Also I think you don't need double quotes round `android_metadata` as it is not an SQL keyword.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the quote symbol (and fix a typo - DEAFULT)

```
stat.executeUpdate("create table \"android_metadata\" (\"locale\" TEXT DEFAULT 'en-US');");
```

Comment: thanx men to b honest i was trying to back slash it but with / rather then using \ the bugs who eats your life ...
thank u :)

Answer (score 2):

The java String equivalents are:

```
// CREATE TABLE "android_metadata" ("locale" TEXT DEFAULT 'en_US')
final static private String create = "CREATE TABLE \"android_metadata\" (\"locale\" TEXT DEFAULT 'en_US')";

// INSERT INTO "android_metadata" VALUES ('en_US')
final static private String insert = "INSERT INTO \"android_metadata\" VALUES ('en_US')";
```

**EDIT**
upgraded the code according to duffymos comment :)

Comment: Both these Strings should be static and final.

Comment: @duffymo, this is just a java-like example how the String should look like. Not even a snippet.

Comment: You and I know that, but the OP doesn't.  S/he had them embedded in the execute method.  I thought it'd be worth pointing out.